# Initialize Singletons in Spring Framework 3 MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, singleton

I am writing Spring 3.1.0 MVC based application. The problem is: i want to put some objects in a singleton object (current `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpSevletResponse`) to use them in other objects(Spring Controllers). But couldn't do so. I tried to extend `DispatcherServlet`, overriding both `doService` and `doDispatch`. Also tried to implement own `HandlerInterceptor`. No result.

Where can I initialize my singleton objects? And where is Spring Frameworks's entry point and destroy point (i.e. like `init()` and `destroy()` methods or lifecycle)?

Comment: Hmm, lots of questions. I think you need to read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The current `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` are available as method arguments to your controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public String foo(HttpServletRequest request) {

}
```

I believe you can also `@Inject` them in your controller. A proxy will be injected, and each time you refer to them the current ones will be used. (I'm not 100% certain about this one)

A third option is to use the `RequestContextHolder` container, and get everything from there.

Comment: Yes. I know these ways. Thanks. But the thing is i am implementing a Facade pattern. That is, to access all my data, which i only can access from Spring framework, put in one object (e.g. spring message, get locales etc). That's why I want to put them in singleton. Do you know how to achieve the initialization of the singleton?

Comment: controllers are singletons as well. I don't understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Initialize my singleton, so i am able to access it in controllers.

Comment: that alone is nothing special - you have a `@Component` (singleton by default) which you `@Inject` in your `@Controller` beans.

Comment: OK. But what about current HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse i want to store in that singleton?! They are the main things.

Comment: Try injecting them. OR use the `RequestContextHolder` to get them. Or simply use a `HandlerInterceptor` which gets them

Comment: So you want to have a Singleton - which is by definition the only object of that kind in the JVM at that moment - to have a HttpServletRequest stored in it. Which is always request dependent, and therefore would mess up things if ever more than one request was made to you server at the same time.

Comment: @JukkaDahlbom this is achievable through proxies, but I still don't get the point of it all :)