# java spring @component scope and HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, scope, spring-boot, autowired

One of my classes deals with HttpServletRequest and is a component like this:

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationService {

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    public Boolean authorize(Integer fetId) {
       ...play with headers, db and other stuff...
    }
```

and is used somewhere else like this

```
public class CarRestController {
    @Autowired
    CarService service; 
    @Autowired
    AuthorizationService authorizer;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Car> get()throws Exception {
        authorizer.authorize(666);
        ...
        return cars;
    }
```

My worry is that since AuthorizationService is a @component, it will be a singleton by default and therefore there can only be one request that will be swapped by newer ones coming as it is processed.

Should I do this to solve the problem?

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class AuthorizationService {
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Why autowire it, what is wrong with passing it into the method?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Scope` on the service and don't worry, your controller is also a singleton (because it's managed by spring).

BTW: you are missing a `@Controller` on your controller

Some reading:

- [Spring framework reference: The IoC container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans)
- [Must Spring MVC Classes be Thread-Safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795303/must-spring-mvc-classes-be-thread-safe)

Answer (score 0):

Spring takes care of request scoped object like HttpServletRequest automatically. Remove `@Scope` and you should be fine.