# How to model response variable as response from the backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

in the below example, i am trying make post and get requests. the POST request was executed correctly. For the GET request, i exepected to get 2121.
but actually, i get nothing which means "this.str" was not set to 2121

is there any way to model a variable to json? normally if the response is an object it will be modelled to json and consequently to the model class.
int he below case, the response is a varibale

is there any why to model a vraible as json object

**Controller1**

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/call1")
public class Call1 {

public String str = "inti";

@RequestMapping(value = "/initparam1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void initparam1(@RequestBody(required = false) String val) {
    this.str = val;
}

@RequestMapping("/getparam1")
public String getParam1() {
    return this.str;
}
}
```

**post_request_postman**

```
http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?val=2121
executed correctly
```

**get_request_postman**

```
http://localhost:8085/call1/getparam1   
result:does not return the value set to str which is 2121
```

Comment: What have u chosen to be your answer to this question, or none of our suggestions worked?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
render this.str;
```

instead of:

```
return this.str;
```

?

Also annotate your method with `@ResponseBody`

Comment: thanyks for the answer.render is not recognized and i added the @ResponseBody but still nothing work

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong at first step.

POST to `http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?val=2121` means 'send body to url initparam1?val=2121' - it's just and url, the same like initparam1_val_2121.

I guess, to this url you send an empty body - so empty string is set to `this.str`, which later is returned from GET.

Or check POST by curl:

```
# correct
curl -d "val=2121" -X POST http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1

# your case, incorrect
curl -d "" -X POST http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?val=2121
```

Comment: thx i dont know how to use curl, i am using postman and it does not use curt. can u please coorect my request http://localhost:8085/call1/initparam1?val=2121

Answer (score 0):

You are doing two things wrongly.

1.Firstly the post request (/initparam1) accepts "val" as a json body but u are passing it as a query parameter u may want to fix that.

2. Secondly, REST is stateless therefore the value of "str" variable cannot be retrieve via a second request unless it is persisted somewhere for retrieval later.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the idea that controllers are thread safe means each request is bound to a thread which has his own data copy of the controller class 
So when you do `/post` `str` was updated on a different thread, when doing `/get` you will have a fresh copy of `str` since you are taking to a new thread.

more details see this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16795572/1460591